# DSAL query for Unread mail in the filter for Outlook using Inbox.Items.Restrict

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I am writing a code for automatically downloading an attachment from unread mail containing several keywords in the subject for example "training" but when I tried using SQL query for unread mail, it's giving me an error.

```
  Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
               Chr(34) & " Like '%Training%' AND " & _
               Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
               Chr(34) & "=1"
  Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter) 'No error while running this code
```

---

```
 Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "& Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
               Chr(34) & " Like '%Training%' AND" & _
                    Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                    Chr(34) & "= 1" & Chr(34) & "AND" & _
                    Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & _
                    Chr(34) & "= 0"


Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter) 
' Now here it is giving me runtime error '-2147352567(800200009)'
```

All the help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You almost got it,*

*The Error is coming from here **`Chr(34) & "= 1" & Chr(34) & "AND" & _`***

*It Should be **`Chr(34) & "=1 AND " & _`***

---

*Example*

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   Chr(34) & " Like '%Training%' AND " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                   Chr(34) & "=1 AND " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & _
                   Chr(34) & "=0"
```

---

> *<sub>[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax) that DASL filters support includes equivalence, prefix, phrase, and substring matching. Note that when you filter on the Subject property, prefixes such as "RE: " and "FW: " are ignored.</sub>*
>
> ---